# Windows Phone 7 and 8 TextBlock query

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Am trying to split text in a textblock so that it appears like paragraphs where i can even make use of bullets like in Microsoft Word but am unable... Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [RichTextBox](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control), which gives you paragraphs, runs and styling. It doesn't however include bullet-point lists. For this you will need to use HTML in a WebClient.

Comment: You could of course create the bullets manually with the • character.